# Why is the value gone in the txt-file when scrape/parse Forex EurUsd from Dailyfx.com?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, scrape, forex

I'm trying to parse the Forex EurUsd value from Dailyfx.com. I can see the value I want there but when I scrape/parse it i got the value "--" in the txt-file.

Here it is at dailyfx.com:
data-value="1.18218"
[image]

My code I use:

```
import urllib.request

opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)


req = urllib.request.Request("https://www.dailyfx.com/eur-usd", headers={"User-Agent": 
"Chrome"})
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

data=res.read()

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(data))
f.close()
```

When I open the file (test.txt) I will find the empty value:

data-value="---"

When I expect to see, data-value="1.18218".
[image]

Comment: It's generated dynamically by `JS` so you won't see it in the source.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So there is no way to scrape/parse data that is generated dynamically by JS?

Comment: I tried this code and it won't work either.
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/easy-web-scraping-5-lines-of-code-on-dynamic-website-csr-with-python-and-selenium-in-2020-44523c475b5

Answer (score 0):

The website is loaded dynamically, so `urlib` doesn't support it. We can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://www.dailyfx.com/eur-usd"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
# Wait for the page to fully render
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())

driver.quit()
```

---

Note: since your using a context manager to write to the file, there's no reason to close it  using `f.close()`, it will automatically be closed after exiting the `with(...)`  block.